# Differences between PhDs in Australia and France

Tags: phd

Can somebody tell me what are differences between an Australian PhD and a French PhD in terms of applications, requirements, Fees and Scholarship, the way it works once admitted, the kind a successful profile ?

Comment: I would suggest you to first do your own research and look for PhD programs that interest you both in Australia and France. I'm sure you can find the most relevant information on the institutions' web pages. If you have questions regarding a specific point, you can provide the references and ask here. I'm saying this because your question is too broad to be addressed (for example, you are not even saying if you are interested in STEM or humanities), thus it's hard to give you a useful answer.

Comment: A likely duplicate of the canonical question, which has entries for both countries: https://academia.stackexchange.com/q/176908/75368